# cannot run this command because java services are not enabled Sybase 12.5

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I tried to run this procedure `"sp_oledb_getcolumnprivileges"` for oledb connection which i got from [here](http://www.sqlbrowser.com/wikiHTML/sqlbhtml/sybsystemprocs/sp_oledb_getcolumnprivileges.html), i have ran `"sp_configure 'enable java', 1"` and restarted Sybase and my result is

```
 - Default -0,  Memory Used -0, Config Value-1, Run Value -0,
   Unit-switch, Type -static.
```

but when i try to run the procedure the error is still the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're barking up the wrong tree here.
The stored proc you picked up from that web site was not for ASE. As the comments in its header show, it comes from MS SQL Server. It seems quite dumb from whomever runs that web site to execute this on ASE, since it is pretty obvious this won't work -- these are two different brands of databases.

Also, this has nothing to do with Java. The reason you may see error messages in ASE mentioning Java is that this MSSQL Server code seems to call functions that apparently exist in MSSQL but not in ASE. What follows is a standard error message mentioning Java (since you could have written function in Java which you're calling from SQL -- but 99.9% of the time that error message just means you're calling an unknown function).

Bottom line: don't expect the procedure from that web site ever to work in ASE.